# Nokogiri select last-1 option value

Tags: ruby, select, nokogiri

I have the following HTML:

```
<select name="ctl00$cp$cbDzien" id="ctl00_cp_cbDzien" onchange="cbDzienGodzina_onChange(this);" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="-1"></option>
  <option value="2013-10-07">2013-10-07</option>
  <option value="2013-10-08">2013-10-08</option>
  <option value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09</option>
  <option value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10</option>
  <option value="2013-10-11">2013-10-11</option>
  <option value="2013-10-14">2013-10-14</option>
  <option value="2013-10-15">2013-10-15</option>
  <option value="2013-10-16">2013-10-16</option>
  <option value="2013-10-17">2013-10-17</option>
  <option value="2013-10-18">2013-10-18</option>
  <option value="2013-10-23">2013-10-23</option>
  <option value="2013-10-24">2013-10-24</option>
  <option value="2013-10-25">2013-10-25</option>
  <option value="2013-10-28">2013-10-28</option>
  <option value="2013-10-29">2013-10-29</option>
  <option value="2013-10-31">2013-10-31</option>
</select>
```

My code:

```
@get_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
@get_doc .at_css("select#ctl00_cp_cbDzien").each do |d|
    puts d[value]
  end
```

However, I didn't see options with such code, and I also need to select last-1 value (2013-10-29) in my example. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't code as per your need. Here it is :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eot
<select name="ctl00$cp$cbDzien" id="ctl00_cp_cbDzien" onchange="cbDzienGodzina_onChange(this);" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="2013-10-07">2013-10-07</option>
        <option value="2013-10-08">2013-10-08</option>
        <option value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09</option>
        <option value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10</option>
        <option value="2013-10-11">2013-10-11</option>
        <option value="2013-10-14">2013-10-14</option>
        <option value="2013-10-15">2013-10-15</option>
        <option value="2013-10-16">2013-10-16</option>
        <option value="2013-10-17">2013-10-17</option>
        <option value="2013-10-18">2013-10-18</option>
        <option value="2013-10-23">2013-10-23</option>
        <option value="2013-10-24">2013-10-24</option>
        <option value="2013-10-25">2013-10-25</option>
        <option value="2013-10-28">2013-10-28</option>
        <option value="2013-10-29">2013-10-29</option>
        <option value="2013-10-31">2013-10-31</option>

</select>
   eot

doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').each do |node|
  puts node['value']
end
# >> -1
# >> 2013-10-07
# >> 2013-10-08
# >> 2013-10-09
# >> 2013-10-10
# >> 2013-10-11
# >> 2013-10-14
# >> 2013-10-15
# >> 2013-10-16
# >> 2013-10-17
# >> 2013-10-18
# >> 2013-10-23
# >> 2013-10-24
# >> 2013-10-25
# >> 2013-10-28
# >> 2013-10-29
# >> 2013-10-31
```

To get the last value you need to do:

```
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').last['value']
# => "2013-10-31"
```

To get the second last value you need to do:

```
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option')[-2]['value']
# => "2013-10-29"
```

Now see,why your code doesn't print your expected result.

```
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien').size
# => 1
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien')[0].name
# => "select"
```

`doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien')` will give you [**`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) having only one [**`Nokogiri::XML::Node`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html),which is your `select` element.Now to get the `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` of all `option` elements,you need to change the selector rule as below:

```
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').size
# => 17
doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').all?{|nd| nd.name == 'option'}
# => true
```

The above `true` value is telling that the `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` created by `doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option')`, is containing all option elements as `Nokogiri::XML::Node`.

Good one liner can be written using [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) or [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) as below :

```
doc.at_css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option:nth-last-child(2)')['value']
# => "2013-10-29"
doc.at_xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_cp_cbDzien']/option[last()-1]")['value']
# => "2013-10-29"
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `to_a` to get a particular Node from a NodeSet. [NodeSet supports `[]`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri’s [`each` method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-each) iterates over the *attributes* of the node, not the element children. To select all the `option` children of the select, you need to use this CSS:

```
@get_doc.css("select#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option").each do |d|
  # ...
```

(Note this uses [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) not [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css), to get all the `option` nodes.)

Using Nokogiri you can get the second to last child node directly with a psuedo class:

```
@get_doc.at_css("select#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option:nth-last-child(2)")
```

This uses the [`nth-last-child` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-child-pseudo), which Nokogiri has implemented.

Answer (score 0):

`@get_doc .at_css("select#ctl00_cp_cbDzien")` gives you the parent node, `<select>`. Sounds like you want to access one of its children. Use the `children` method.

```
@get_doc.at_css('select#ctl00_cp_cbDzien').children.each { |d| puts d }

#=><option value="-1"></option>
<option value="2013-10-07">2013-10-07</option>
<option value="2013-10-08">2013-10-08</option>
<option value="2013-10-09">2013-10-09</option>
<option value="2013-10-10">2013-10-10</option>
<option value="2013-10-11">2013-10-11</option>
<option value="2013-10-14">2013-10-14</option>
<option value="2013-10-15">2013-10-15</option>
<option value="2013-10-16">2013-10-16</option>
<option value="2013-10-17">2013-10-17</option>
<option value="2013-10-18">2013-10-18</option>
<option value="2013-10-23">2013-10-23</option>
<option value="2013-10-24">2013-10-24</option>
<option value="2013-10-25">2013-10-25</option>
<option value="2013-10-28">2013-10-28</option>
<option value="2013-10-29">2013-10-29</option>
<option value="2013-10-31">2013-10-31</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Nokogiri is a tad rusty but wouldn't it be:

```
length = doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').to_a.count
last_element_minus_one = doc.css('#ctl00_cp_cbDzien option').to_a[length-2]
value = last_element_minus_one["value"]
```

The `-2` is used to find the second to last element.

Comment: `length` not needed: `p ["a", "b", "c", "d"][-2] #=> "c"`

Comment: @steenslag, yup I'm aware of using `-2`. I figured using variable `length` and method `count` was easier to understand for someone new/er to ruby. I felt this way was more explicit. Either way, looks like the OP got enough answers to move on.